# Create multiple Jenkins job for one repo

Tags: jenkins

I want to have two separate jobs run against a repo,
can I have one repo with two separate Jenkinsfile?

need some help on this, tried finding online, but unable to come to find a resolution

Comment: Just give them different names and put that in the job invocation. Jeniknsfile.dev Jenkinsfile.qa, etc.

Comment: Yes. You can have any number of Jenkinsfiles in a repo. Like Ian mentioned in the comment, rename the files as desired and have proper trigger conditions so that only necessary jobs are executed.